How to get Windows always prompt an "open with" dialog?
As said, I want my Windows to always send me to "Open With" dialog, when I try to open a file.
There is a similar XPosed module for Android, named Kill Domain Verification, but it's working only for links.
I somehow managed to block Windows from setting default browser, by deleting some items in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<extension-name> (cannot remember if it was .html or not), and revoking permissions from SYSTEM and %username% (as far as I can remember), but I want those prompts to be for every (or at least some) file types.
What I found:

Revoking access from SYSTEM and %username% from file association, so it cannot be changed
Removing "Always Open With" option from Open With dialog (not working in Win 11)
Removing file associations (Win 8.1)
Creating a dummy.exe to set to it


 there was even this post with "UnForTUnaTeLy, ThIs iS nOT a ConFiGuRaBle OpTiOn."(sorry, that was so stupid, that I got mad)

I would appreciate any help, either it will be changing registry/permissions or using specific programs to forward to chosen programs.
P.S. I use latest build 23H2 22631.3527.

Use the assoc command to remove (or set) file associations. For example, to be asked how to open .readme files,

Press Windows and type cmd.
Select CMD and press CtrlShiftEnter to get the Command prompt as Administrator.
Type assoc .readme and press Enter to see the current association (e.g., .readme=Notepad++_file, on this PC).
Type assoc .readme= and press Enter to remove the current association
Type assoc .readme=Notepad++_file and press Enter to restore that old association.

You can also try the following to remove the default file handlers, if assoc does not work.

Add a portable app (later to be removed) as a "dummy", such as HxD Hex Editor, that can open any file type.
For each file type, select "Open with".
Choose "Look for another app on this PC" or "Choose another app".
Set "Always use this app to open .xxx files".
Select the dummy app and press OK.
Remove the dummy app (or just rename the app extension other than exe, to test the first file type changed, to be sure thsi works as you want on your PC).

N.B. Certain file types are reserved by MS Windows for executable and other special purposes, e.g., EXE, BAT, COM, MSI. Other file extensions, such as .java, .class, .jar, .jmod, must be associated with the Java runtime for it to work. Changing the file assaciation
